# "Bad request" is shown when try to startup "Kaazing Simple Chat App"

Tags: websocket, kaazing, browser-based

To test KWG, as Kazzing suggested, tried to run [template-simple-chat-app-master](https://github.com/kaazing/template-simple-chat-app) & follow instruction steps, up to step 3, it was successfully done and "chat server" & "Kaazing WebSocket Gateway" correctly started. but when tried to connect client/agent URLs, there was no response and 400 code was replied from server! 
default port "8080" is free. however other port was tested and the response was the same.
tried it in Win 10.
Can anyone give an advice to solve the problem?
thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a *known issue* that there is *no Windows script* for step 3.

Since *the template runs just fine on Linux*, it is safe to say that **the problem lies within the startup script you have created** for step 3. There are *a lot of environment variable configurations which are very easy to get wrong*.

We recommend that you **run the chat app template on Linux**. But if you must use Windows, *you should revise the aforementioned script*.